# how to create a trigger function onCreate() in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am not able to create an onCreate function for firebase cloud functions.
I want to get data of the order when a new order is placed by user.
Here is my function:

```
exports.createOrder = functions.firestore.document('Orders/{now}/Live Orders/{orderID}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const order = snap.data();
    //const ordertime = order.orderTime;
```

Here "now" is the current date which I am getting though this:

```
var d = new Date();
var month = parseInt(d.getMonth(),0) + 1;
var now = d.getFullYear() + "-"+ month + "-"+ d.getDate();
```

The error which I am getting is something like this:

```
Failed to configure trigger providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create@firestore.googleapis.com (createOrder)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the *entire, minimal code* that causes this error.

Comment: More information are definitely needed. How you used the onCreate() function seem appropriate. Nothing seems off, following the details provided in this [Trigger link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) but it is unclear how your operation is being done. You should show more of your application code on how the operations are done and how it leads to the error.